# Contradiction of the Borel sigma-field when we think the set of irrational numbers.

Tags: borel-sets

I understand the sigma-field as not allowing uncountable union or intersection. In set of irrational numbers, it is the Borel set because it is a complement set of rational numbers. But if we think it as a union of the irrational numbers, it is a uncountable union and it can't be the Borel set. How do I think about Borel set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is *some* way to build the set from countable intersections/unions and complements from open sets, it is Borel. Otherwise it's not (and showing a set to be *non*-Borel is much harder than witnessing it *is*  a Borel set).

As $\Bbb P$ (the irrationals) *can* be written as the complement of a countable set and each countable set is a countable union of singletons which are closed (and thus the complement of an open set), you *have* a valid verification that $\Bbb P$ is in $\text{Bor}(\Bbb R)$. There it stops, you don't have to think about ways it is *not* Borel anymore.

Most sets that you can write down explicitly will be Borel in this way. Of course it suffices to build a set up from sets that you already know to be Borel and as long as you only use the $\sigma$-algebra operations you're guaranteed to still get Borel sets and only Borel sets.

If you find an invalid "proof" of a statement it doesn't mean the statement is false. That is a logical fallacy. We just need one good proof for the statement to be true.

Comment: Thanks for your considerate explanation. It is a nice sentence "an invalid proof of a statement does not mean the statement is false"

Comment: @이선훈 Thx. I added that later as it seemed to be the central issue in your problems.